# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos

Below error occurs while I was writing two functions xxxx as part of uni work. The IDE I'm using is **Visual Studio Code**.

The problem was that when I tried to compile a single file in the folder **code/myIO**, it threw an error:

(I've replaced the folder's path with ($). I promise the problem wasn't there)

```
cd ($) && clang++ r.cpp -o ($)/r -D LOCAL -Wall -O2 -fsanitize=undefined

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_Tp::INT", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in r-ebf422.o
  "_Tp::fmt", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in r-ebf422.o
  "_Tp::str", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in r-ebf422.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's more, when I tried to link some files, similar error happened.

```
clang++ -shared -o libmystdio.so myscanf.o myprintf.o
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_Tp::INT", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myscanf.o
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myprintf.o
  "_Tp::fmt", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myscanf.o
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myprintf.o
  "_Tp::str", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myscanf.o
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myprintf.o
  "_Tp::LONG", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myscanf.o
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myprintf.o
  "_Tp::LONGLONG", referenced from:
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myscanf.o
      split(char const*, _Tp*) in myprintf.o
  "_out_buf", referenced from:
      myprintf(char const*, ...) in myprintf.o
  "_out_idx", referenced from:
      myprintf(char const*, ...) in myprintf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libmystdio.so] Error 1
```

In case you wonder what I've written, [please click here](https://github.com/NaughtyEric/MyOI).  However it's not finished,I doubt you would be interested...(I made a few comments and most of them are in Chinese, for my groupmates to read)

And, files in folder **code** aren't affected. They can be compiled and run normally.Only those in folder **code/myIO** went wrong.

Here's my clang++ version:

```
clang++ -v
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) If not, please update your question with details that will distinguish your issue from what the other question covers. A [mre] would help, just make sure it reproduces the error message and comes with an explanation of why you believe the error message is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a declaration without a definition.

`utilities.h` has:

```
class _Tp {
  // [...]
public:
  // [...]
  static const int INT = 1, SHORT = 2, LONG = 3, LONGLONG = 4,
      FLOAT = 10, DOUBLE = 11, LONGDOUBLE = 12;
```

That declares `_Tp::INT` etc. with initializers, but does not define them. If you ODR-use these values then you need to have a definition for them, meaning that there needs to be a single place designated to hold the bytes of memory for these constants in your program.[0]

The normal way to do this is to have a matching `utilities.cpp` with:

```
const int _Tp::INT;
const int _Tp::SHORT;
const int _Tp::LONG;
const int _Tp::LONGLONG;
const int _Tp::FLOAT;
const int _Tp::DOUBLE;
const int _Tp::LONGDOUBLE;
```

but in your case you might want to consider switching to an enum! To do that you would write in `utilities.h`:

```
class _Tp {
  // [...]
public:
  // [...]
  enum { INT = 1, SHORT = 2, LONG = 3, LONGLONG = 4,
      FLOAT = 10, DOUBLE = 11, LONGDOUBLE = 12 };
```

then you don't need a `utilities.cpp`.

[0] There's a special-case for allowing values of integral types to be ODR-used without being defined in narrow circumstances, but I recommend that programmers not rely on it. A non-expert makes a innocent change to the code and gets a confusing link error.

Comment: It did work! I can compile r.cpp now.

Comment: Great to hear it!!

Comment: Sorry for troubling you again, but when I fixed those problems in the project files and build it again, errors about "_out_buf" and "_out_idx" remained. Confusingly, I have not define an variable or function with this name.In fact, "out_buf" and "out_idx" were defined in **main.cpp**, and `extern char out_buf[]` and `extern int out_idx` have been added in **myprintf.cpp**. I asked my instructor about that, but he failed to figure out why.

Comment: The leading `_` is always present on Mac, that's just part of the platform ABI for C and C++ code. Your variable and function names when compiled through clang or gcc on Mac will be prefixed with an `_` in the object file.

The reason it doesn't link is probably the "libmystdio.so" rule in the makefile which attempts to combine `myprintf.o` into a shared object (note, on Mac should be named `.dylib`) without including the main.cpp where is where you define `out_buf` and `out_idx`.